# What's the difference between using `: Interface` and `as Interface` in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure what these are called so I'm having a bit of trouble searching for an answer. Let's say I have the following interface defined:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

What's the difference between the following?

```js
const foo: Person = getPerson(data);
```

and

```js
const foo = getPerson(data) as Person;
```

Seems like both tell TS that `foo` is a `Person`. Is there fundamentally any difference or is it just a matter of using whatever floats my boat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
const foo: Person = getPerson(data);
```

you tell the compiler: I assume that `getPerson` returns something that implements the `Person` interface, please check that and scold me if it doesn't.

```
const foo = getPerson(data) as Person;
```

is an assertion, with which you assure the compiler that `getPerson` returns a `Person`, even if they mean otherwise. Basically, it's a way to shut up the type checker, and, mostly, not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
const foo: Person = getPerson(data);
```

Is a type annotation, and means you're saying "I want `foo` to be of type `Person`". However, if `getPerson(data)` returns something *other* than a `Person`, TypeScript will say "No no no, that's not allowed. You want `Person` but `getPerson(data)` does not return that, bad!"

---

```
const foo = getPerson(data) as Person;
```

`as Person` is a type assertion, if you wrote this without the `as Person`, TypeScript would infer `foo` to be the type of whatever `getPerson(data)` returns. However, by adding the `as Person` you are telling TypeScript, explicitly, "Whatever this function returns, even if it's not actually a `Person`, I am forcing you to type it as a `Person`".

Hope that answers it somewhat.